# Bash Comparison with Subtraction

Tags: bash

How do I do this in bash:

```
while (var1 < (var2 - 1)) {
    ...
}
```

Right now, this is what I have in bash:

```
while [ $var1 < $var2-1 ]
do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use double parentheses to make an arithmetic statement.

```
while ((var1 < (var2 - 1)))
do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

since

```
a=2; b=3; [ $a -gt $(($b-1)) ] && echo yes || echo no
```

then the script would be like

```
while [ $var1 -lt $(($var2-1)) ]; do
  ...
done
```